# FB.api post to wall : access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, token

I'm trying to post to the facebook wall of a connected user using the javascript sdk, here is my code :

```
     var connecter=false;
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // App ID
      oauth      : true,
      channelUrl : '//www.streamazing.net/js/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
               window.location.reload();
            });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
               window.location.reload();
            });



    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                connecter=true;
                FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                var user2=user;
                console.log(user2.name);

                });

            }
        else connecter=false;
        });





    var body = 'This is a test';
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        console.log(response.error);
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });
};
```

Here is the console log :

```
code: 2500
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"
```

I'm asking the permission with this code :

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink='true'  scope='email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream'></fb:login-button>
```

I don't understand why facebook is asking me an access token, can someone help me ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: can you tell me how you solved the problem i am also stuck at the same problem?????

Answer (score 0):

Use FB.ui instead if you want to use the Javascript SDK to post to a user's feed.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Otherwise, the access token required for the publish_stream extended permission is stored within the FB.getLoginStatus method under response.authResponse.accessToken.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make request with access_token= to all the FB URLs.

Answer (score 0):

call FB.init(); after all the fb sdk functions were declared.